# count rows and give values of the rows

Tags: sql, count

Probably really simple but I can't quite figure it out.

Here's my SQL

```
select ag.product_id, COUNT(reviewer) as review_number    
from PRODUCT ag    
left join RATINGANDREVIEW rr on rr.product_id = ag.product_id
where ag.product_id = 123
group by ag.product_id
```

This is giving me total number of reviews made for one product as follows:

> Product_id: 123
>
> review_number: 3

but I now want the reviewers names as well like so:

> Product_id: 123
>
> review_number: 3
>
> reviewer: Bob Smith
>
> Product_id: 123
>
> review_number: 3
>
> reviewer: Peter Jones
>
> Product_id: 123
>
> review_number: 3
>
> reviewer: Jane Green

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
select 
ag.product_id, 
reviewer,

(select COUNT(reviewer) 
from PRODUCT ag
left join RATINGANDREVIEW rr on rr.product_id = ag.product_id
where ag.product_id = 123) as review_number

from PRODUCT ag
left join RATINGANDREVIEW rr on rr.product_id = ag.product_id
where ag.product_id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select ag.product_id, COUNT(reviewer) as review_number, rr.reviewer_name
from PRODUCT ag    
left join RATINGANDREVIEW rr on rr.product_id = ag.product_id
where ag.product_id = 123
group by ag.product_id,rr.reviewer_name
```

Comment: I think Count(reviewer) here would be always 1, unless there are more than one review of the same person for one product.